# ERC-721 Smart contract is minting 2 NFTs at a time

Tags: ethereum, solidity, nft

I have this smart contract from Hash Lip's github that, from what I can tell should be minting 1 at a time, but is instead minting 2 every time.  Code as follows:

Setup code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

// Created by HashLips
// The Nerdy Coder Clones

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract TestBoxes is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
  using Strings for uint256;

  string public baseURI;
  string public baseExtension = ".json";
  uint256 public cost = 0.01 ether;
  uint256 public maxSupply = 3;  //there should only be 3 minted (I have 3 image files to test)
  uint256 public maxMintAmount = 3;
  bool public paused = false;
  mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted;
```

And then the part where the contract is minting is as follows.  as you can see above, I have set the max as 3, and in the next part, after the constructor executes, it mints 1 NFT for the owner.

```
  constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI
  ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    mint(msg.sender, 1); //should mint 1 at deployment but mints 2...
  }

  // internal
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return baseURI;
  }

  // public
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(!paused);
    require(_mintAmount > 0);
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        if(whitelisted[msg.sender] != true) {
          require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
        }
    }

    for (uint256 i = 0; i <= _mintAmount; i++) { //start the index at 0
      _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to say anything bad about hashlips but you should probably find a different source for your smart contract code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a logical error in the `for` loop within the `mint()` function.

```
for (uint256 i = 0; i <= _mintAmount; i++)
```

Example: `_mintAmount` is `1` (same as passing from the constructor).

- First iteration:

  `i` is `0`, which is **less or equal 1**

  => performs the iteration and executes the `_safeMint()`
- Second iteration:

  `i` is `1`, which is **less or equal 1**

  => it still performs the iteration and executes the `_safeMint()`

---

Fix it by changing the condition to `i < _mintAmoun` (**i is less than**). Then it will only execute once (for `mintAmount` value 1).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++)
```

The way above works the same way.